# Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `-`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ethereum

I am running a code snippet as follow:

```
renderPropositions() {
        const items = this.props.propositionAddress.map(async address => {
            // get the instance of deployed contract
            const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(Proposition.interface), address);

            const title = await instance.methods.pTitle().call();

            return {
                header: title,
                meta: address
            }
        });

        return <Card.Group items={items} />;

    }
```

This continually hit the error above. But when I drop the `async` and `await` functions, there is no error.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You get the warning because your items haven't got a `key` defined, which is used internally by react for reconciliation. This is the way react updates only the parts of the DOM that actually changed. You should read on this two topics, [using keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) and [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

You should show the code where you actually render the items (in `Card.Group`?), if you want a more detailed answer on how to remove the warning.

Comment: Hi, it is rendered in `Card.Group`, and the whole thing is rendered in `render()` function

Comment: How does the `Card.Group` render method look like?